# Ocultar valor de una celda

Tags: excel, excel-2013

tengo el resultado de concatenar dos celdas  (con un poco de logica) en una celda.  lo que pretendo, es esconder  el valor de la celda cuando no hay valores en las 2 celdas inciales.

```
           G                                          C
  _____________________                        ___________________________
12|        fname      |                     15 |fname.lname@domain.com    |
  _____________________                        ____________________________
13|       lname       |                        
  _____________________
```

si estos dols valores  no existen  quiero ocultar el valor de C15. Actualmente  me queda un remanente de **@domain.com**

```
           G                                          C
  _____________________                        ___________________________
12|                    |                    15 |          @domain.com    |
  _____________________                        ____________________________
13|                    |                        
  _____________________
```

El valor de C15 lo saco con la sig formula

```
LOWER(IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",G12)-1),G12,LEFT(G12,FIND(" ",G12)-1))&"."&IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",G13)-1),G13,LEFT(G13,FIND(" ",G13)-1))&"@smurfitkappa.com")
```

Comment: *cuando no hay valores en las 2 celdas iniciales*. Usa un IF y un COUNTBLANK. Si el resultado de la cuenta es 2, significa que las 2 celdas están vacías y no tienen valores, así que devuelve `""`. Si la cuenta no es 2, pues que haga tu fórmula. Algo así deberías poder adaptarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta formula puede solucionar el problema que expones:

```
=IF(OR(G12=0,G13=0),"",LOWER(G12&"."&G13&"@gmail.com"))
```

`IF/SI` condicional
`OR/O` evalúa los parámetros y si **AL MENOS UNO ES VERDADERO (TRUE)** devuelve un **VERDADERO (TRUE)**. De tal forma si `G12` o `G13` son igual a cero, o están vacías, entonces el `IF` nos devuelve una string vacía (no un cero), en caso contrario
`LOWER`, nos devuelve en minúsculas, el concatenado que se muestra en la formula.

Avísame si te sirve.